# Почему JInput вырезает из параметра кириллические символы

Tags: joomla

Воспроизвел проблему в своем компоненте для Joomla. При передаче параметров через URL вырезаются все кириллические символы, которые есть в переданном значении.

Например мне нужен последний параметр (id):

http://mysite.ru/index.php?option=com_restapi&view=categories&format=raw&id=31

получаю 31

[http://mysite.ru/index.php?option=com_restapi&view=photos&format=photo&isThumb=true&id=сашатаня](http://mysite.ru/index.php?option=com_restapi&view=photos&format=photo&isThumb=true&id=%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F)

получаю пустое значение

[http://mysite.ru/index.php?option=com_restapi&view=photos&format=photo&isThumb=true&id=сашатаня2](http://mysite.ru/index.php?option=com_restapi&view=photos&format=photo&isThumb=true&id=%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F2)

получаю 2

Путем отладки удалось сузить область поиска до этой строчки кода в одном из контроллеров:

```
$id = $this->input->get('id');
// отладочный код
$id2 = $_GET['id'];
echo "id: $id, id2: $id2";
```

Выводит: `id:, id2: сашатаня`

Здесь, переменная input содержит объект JInput, и вывод echo показывает что значение параметра в массиве $_GET такое, какое было передано. Однако JInput->get возвращает уже обрезанное значение.

Мне необходимо разрешить пользователю вводить этот параметр самому, в том числе и использовать кириллические символы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей вероятности JInput->get ничего не обрезает, а просто возвращает `INT`, попробуйте явно указать что вам нужна строка:

`JInput->getString('id');`